# Are we still support iPhone 3.5" screen to meet app store guidelines?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, appstore-approval

I found that my app got dis approved by apple because the app doesn't follow app store guideline on running app in iPad. This is what apple is saying

**Your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad. While your app may be built for iPhone or iPod, it must still run on iPad, at iPhone resolution and at 2x iPhone 3GS resolution.**

Since I need to support only iPhone 5 devices and above which are 4" devices, I still don't understand why apple is asking us to support 3.5" screen so that they run correctly on iPads.

Does anyone know why this so?

Thnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange but true. There is no way to disable support for 3.5" devices. You must support both sizes because an iPhone app must run on iPad as well which simulates a 3.5" device.

One of our apps also got rejected for not supporting 3.5" screen as the reviewer also tested it on iPad.

Comment: It appears that we need to support 3.5" as I able to digest from couple of emails from apple.