# How do I make my app compatible with only iPhone 5 and Above?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I wish to make my app only compatible with 4 inch screens and above. Is there a simple way that I can do this? One of my ideas was to set required device capabilities in the plist so it only includes the iPhone 5 and above's processor, but I don't know how to implement this. Thanks!

Comment: You should have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351526/are-we-still-support-iphone-3-5-screen-to-meet-app-store-guidelines

Comment: So then this is not possible?